# Django app : "URL not found" error when i run my server

Tags: python, django, web-development-server

I have begun to learn web dev using django. I my first app I am not able to see my web page when I run the command :

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Here is my code snippet:

```
#view.py(in app folder)
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello World!")

#urls.py (in project folder)
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from first_app import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('^$',views.index,name='index'),
    path('^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I have created the environment and activated it also.

Here's the output on  my web page screen.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in first_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^$ [name='index']
^admin/
The empty path didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to 
False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Answer (score 0):

That I think is incorrect syntax, you don't need to use ^$ with path(). 
Just use

```
path("", views.index, name='index'),
path("admin/", admin.site.urls)
```